# react-native how to set-up PickerItems like color of text, fontSize etc,

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, styles

I have Picker from 'react-native'. Picker.Item there are :"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc". And I want to set up text properties. Like fontSize:20, color:"red" etc.

In Picker component we can use style. But there I can't change properties of text. Also I try to use ItemStyle={{color:"red"}}. But nothing change

```
<Picker
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            selectedValue={this.props.shift}
            onValueChange={value => this.props.employeeUpdate({ prop: 
'shift', value })}
          >
            <Picker.Item label="Monday" value="Monday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Thuesday" value="Thuesday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Wednesdady" value="Wednesdady" />
            <Picker.Item label="Thursday" value="Thursday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Friday" value="Friday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Saturday" value="Saturday" />
            <Picker.Item label="Sunday" value="Sunday" />
          </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by the docs, `itemStyle` works only on iOS and has to be used on the global Picker component like:`<Picker itemStyle={styles.pickerItemStyle}`.

I'm pretty sure using the classic react-native `Picker` you can only change the color of an item using the prop `color`.
 These are the only props usable from `Picker.item` as said by the react-native docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker-item

Comment: Yes i got it, but I want to change text's color, because my global background color like blue and black. And it's hard to see Picker.Item's text

Comment: To change the text color just use `<Picker.item color="yellow"/>`. Tested on my device and works

Comment: Maybe use another picker from nativebase?